# Summing results of some formula applied to each cell of column

Tags: excel

I have the following data in my excel table:

```
                01.04.2020  02.04.2020  ...
Employee 01     
Employee 02                 7:31-16:39
Employee 03     8:02-17:04  
Employee 04
Employee 05
Employee 06     5:37-8:21   5:31-8:06
Employee 07     8:02-19:42  
Employee 08                 8:11-21:44
Employee 09     9:48-19:45  8:40-21:05
Employee 10     9:40-19:45  
Employee 11     
Employee 12                 7:47-16:42
Employee 13     
Employee 14     
Employee 15     9:52-19:43  9:51-20:00
```

I've managed to calculate total time spent by each employee with the following formula:

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(B2;LEN(B2)-FIND("-";B2)))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(B2;FIND("-";B2)-1))
```

But I can't figure out how can I calculate the sum of this formula results for each day. Can it be done with excel without adding additional columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (for regional settings using commas in formulas)

```
=SUM(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(B2:B16,LEN(B2:B16)-FIND("-",B2:B16)))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(B2:B16,FIND("-",B2:B16)-1)),0))
```

And for your regional settings that use semicolons instead of commas)

```
=SUM(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(B2:B16;LEN(B2:B16)-FIND("-";B2:B16)))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(B2:B16;FIND("-";B2:B16)-1));0))
```

In Office 365 with Dynamic Arrays that formula will work by confirming with just the Enter key. I'm not sure if it will work in older versions of Excel at all, but if so, only after confirming with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: Thanks, it works in Excel 2013 with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, and according to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) article it should work with any Excel version starting from 2007. I wonder why I see commas in all examples while my Excel accepts only semicolons. Turns out it depends on regional settings. An interesting design solution from Microsoft )

Comment: The semicolon is due to your regional settings. US uses comma, many European regions use the semicolon as the list separator. If you send a workbook between different computers, Excel will do the conversion. But if you copy and paste a formula from the internet, you need to pay attention to what symbol the formula uses and replace it if it is not the symbol YOUR system uses.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it once with a column and once without the extra column as per your request. Generally you need to use keystroke CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER in order to make this work but because we used SUMPRODUCT formula this keystroke was removed. Picture is attached and formula below.
=SUMPRODUCT(
IFERROR(
TIMEVALUE(  RIGHT(C2:C16,  LEN(C2:C16)-FIND("-",  C2:C16))  )-
TIMEVALUE(  LEFT(C2:C16,FIND("-",C2:C16)-1)  ),
0) *24)
[image]

Comment: No matter if I use `=SUM` or `=SUMPRODUCT` in Excel 2013 it works only with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.